# how to implement optiontransferselect using ajax

Tags: ajax, struts2

I'm trying to implement `optiontransferselect` using ajax. I can not move the values from left side to right side.I've added `<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>` tags in my code and I've included `<sx:head/>` also, but it doesn't work. please help me out to solve the issue.

my.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>
<head>
<sx:head/>
</head>

 <div class="width2 margin-bottom margin-top">
                <div class="profile-text">
                    Preferred Location
                </div>

                 <s:optiontransferselect  
                 id="city"
                 name="cityNo"
                 list="cityList"
                 listKey="id"
                 listValue="cityName"
                 headerKey="0"
                 headerValue="City"
                 onfocus="getcitywithCountry(false);"

                 doubleList="prefererList"
                 doubleId="city"
                 doubleListKey="cityId.id" 
                 doubleListValue="cityId.cityName"
                 doubleHeaderKey="0"
                 doubleHeaderValue="--selected locations--"   
                 doubleName="selectedLocations" allowUpDownOnLeft="false" allowUpDownOnRight="false"/>

            </div>
```

Comment: Which version of Struts2?

Comment: the version which I'm using is 2.3.1.2

Comment: @UmarMuktharKadherIbrahim You don't need `dojo` to run `optiontransferselect` in `struts2`. Can you post your complete jsp?

Comment: @UmarMuktharKadherIbrahim In Struts 2.3.1.2 dojo plugin is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see much wrong with your code. You need to remove `<%@ taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sx"%>` reference. Replace `<sx:head/>` with `<s:head/>`.